# cookie not saved by browser

Tags: reactjs, go, cookies, go-gin

Tried [15648070](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76286833/15648070),[15648070](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76427369/15648070) and didn't work unfortunately :)

Hi there, first time building an API with Gin, and I'm having some issues setting a cookie on my browser

I mean, when viewing the request on `dev tools` I see the `Set-Cookie` header and the correct value, also under `Cookie` tab within that request I also see the cookie there

The main issue it's not saved on my browser (`dev tools` -> `Application` -> `Storage` -> `Cookies` and my cookies are not there   )

backend :

```
router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "Content-Length", "Content-Type"},
        MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
        AllowAllOrigins:  true,
        AllowCredentials: true,
    }))

    router.POST("/users/login", server.LoginUser)
```

```
func (server *Server) LoginUser(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ...
    ctx.SetCookie("access_token", accessToken, 3600, "/", "localhost", false, true)
    ctx.SetCookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, 3600, "/", "localhost", false, true)

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"ok": true, "payload": rsps})

}
```

frontend :

```
const login = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  };
  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login Page</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
         ...
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Any clue .. ?

Comment: `fetch` should be called with `mode: 'cors'` and `credentials: 'include'`. If it still does not work, please provide a self-contained demo like https://stackoverflow.com/a/76295116/1369400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks to `#Reactiflux` channel on `Discord`)

I was missing 2 things ..

servers side :

- `AllowHeaders` headers -> adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization"`
- Adding `AllowOriginFunc` -> meaning not allowing `*` rather a specific domain

frontend side :

- Adding `withCredentials: true` to my `axios` config